# The array is not sorted to the end, how can this be done?

Tags: c#

I don't sort the values to the end in the array. Help, what should I do? I've tried several ways, all with the same result.

```
array2 = needItems.FindAll(x => x.nameTypeProduct == "Колесо").ToArray();
//initialy //11145 | 10161| 14804 | 11509 | 11959 | | 3445 | 8439 |13892
var k = array2.ToArray().OrderBy(x => x.cost); 
//result //10161 | 11145 | 11509 | 11959 | 13892 | 14804 | 3445 | 8439
```

Comment: Is the `cost` field/property a string?

Comment: Yes, a property of type string

Comment: Then you want something like `OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.cost))` instead - it's currently sorting correctly, but _alphabetically_, because the value is a string.

Comment: Thanks!! I've broken my whole head, which is why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The resulting sequence:

```
10161 | 11145 | 11509 | 11959 | 13892 | 14804 | 3445 | 8439
```

*is* sorted, but it's alphabetically, because the ranking value resolved by `x => x.cost` is a *string*.

Change it so that it resolves to an integral type and it'll sort them by numerical value instead:

```
var k = array2.ToArray().OrderBy(x => int.TryParse(x.cost, out int cost) ? cost : int.MaxValue);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this will throw an exception if any of the values cannot be parsed into an integer.

Comment: @DavidG Good point, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Better, though of course it all depends on what OP wants to happen in case of a bad item. In many cases, that may mean the entire set is unreliable.